# Unicode char' (U+301) --> References do not update

Tags: biblatex, biber, unicode, sharelatex

I have a problem within ShareLaTex. I get the following error message:

```
Unicode char' (U+301)
```

I received it after adding references to my bib file. `U+301` seems to refer to ~ signs or accents. That makes sense since I tried to input some Czech names including accents on letters.

What is strange: by now I deleted all of the references that I had recently  added as I suspected a problem in them. Still, the References will not update after compiling.

I am using the following specifications:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=bwl-FU]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography1.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
```

Comment: Try to delete the temporary files, especially the `.bbl` and if that does not help also the `.bcf`.

Comment: Since you are using ShareLaTeX here are a few pointers on how to remove temporary files there: [How do you make Biblatex work in ShareLaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264100/35864), [http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284342/35864](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284342/35864).

Comment: You are my hero of the day ;)

Comment: @moewe -- since your comments seem to have answered the question, maybe an actual answer is in order.  and an addition of sharelatex to the tags.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done!

Answer (score 6):

The evil characters still reside in the `.bbl` file (which is read by TeX when it prints the bibliography) even after the `.bib` was updated. A Biber run is required for these changes to propagate to the `.bbl`.

The Biber run, however, can only succeed if the `.bcf` file (which `biblatex` uses to communicate with Biber) is well-formed. If the LaTeX run had to be aborted due to an error, often the `.bcf` is malformed.

This can leave you in a vicious circle of malformed files. (The handling of those has changed recently, so you might be fine after a few runs if you plough on ignoring the errors).

To make sure the problem does not appear you have to remove the `.bbl` and `.bcf` files and recompile.

In ShareLaTeX just press the *Logs & Other Files* button next to *Recompile* and then the little dustbin at the bottom of the rightmost pane, you will be asked to confirm that you want to delete the temporary files. See also [Obtaining .bbl file from sharelatex output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284345/35864)